# Flutter change extends

Tags: flutter, flutter-theme

I want to change the color based on the theme mode. In `AppTheme` I mention var

```
class AppTheme {
  static AppTheme of(BuildContext context) => DarkModeTheme();

  late Color primaryColor;
  late Color secondaryColor;
}
```

In dark mode colors

```
class DarkModeTheme extends AppTheme {
  @override
  Color primaryColor = const Color(0xFFFF5963);
  @override
  Color secondaryColor = const Color(0xFFBE7274);
}
```

In light mode colors

```
class LightModeTheme extends AppTheme {
  @override
  Color primaryColor = const Color(0xFFA71A1C);
  @override
  Color secondaryColor = const Color(0xFFF6F6F6);
}
```

The way I call the color

```
Container(
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  color: AppTheme.of(context).primaryColor,
)
```

Initially, I mentioned the DarkModeTheme(), so the DarkModeTheme primary color is what I have seen. how can I change the LightModeTheme()

Answer (score 0):

make a switch button on your application for exemple Night Mode True or False, and store it in a static parameter appMode,
then change your code as follow

```
 class AppTheme {
  static AppTheme of(BuildContext context) => appMode ==false?  LightModeTheme():DarkModeTheme()

  late Color primaryColor;
  late Color secondaryColor;
}
```

Comment: Great working properly but I need an answer from the provider package. Can please help